# I cannot receive notifications from Firebase Messaging with the app in background

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

In my Flutter app the admin users can send notifications to the others users through FCM. In android already works but in iOS the notification arrives only with the app opened. I already tried many things on internet and still don't working.

This is the dart code that manages the pushs:

```dart
Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
  if (message.containsKey('data')) {
    // Handle data message
    final dynamic data = message['data'];
  }

  if (message.containsKey('notification')) {
    // Handle notification message
    final dynamic notification = message['notification'];
  }

  // Or do other work.
}


class PushNotificationsManager {

  PushNotificationsManager._();

  factory PushNotificationsManager() => _instance;

  static final PushNotificationsManager _instance = PushNotificationsManager
      ._();

  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  final NotificationPlugin _notificationPlugin = NotificationPlugin();

  Future<void> init() async {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
          IosNotificationSettings());
    }
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      // Called when the app is in the foreground and we receive a push notif.
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: ${message}");
        print(message['notification']['body']);
        _notificationPlugin.showNotification(
            title: 'TEST',
            content: message['notification']['body']
        );
        //sendNotification();
      },
      // Called when the app has been closed completely and its opened
      // from the notification directly

      //onBackgroundMessage: Platform.isAndroid ? myBackgroundMessageHandler:null,
      onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
        if(Platform.isIOS){
          message = _modifyNotificationJson(message);
        }
      },
      // Called when the app is in the background and its opened from the notif
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: ${message}");
        if(Platform.isIOS){
          message = _modifyNotificationJson(message);
        }
      },
    );

  }

  Map _modifyNotificationJson(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    message['data'] = Map.from(message ?? {});
    message['notification'] = message['aps']['alert'];
    return message;
  }


  Future sendNotification(String body, String title) async {
    final String url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    var notification;
    notification =
    '{"notification": {"body": "${body}", "title": "${title}", "content_available": "true", "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"}, "priority": "high", "to": "MYTOPIC"}';
    final response = await http.post(
        url,
        headers: <String, String>{
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Keep-Alive": "timeout=5",
          "Authorization": "key=MYKEY"
        },
        body: notification
    );

    print(response.body);
  }
}
```

AppDelegate.swift:

```swift
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

      let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
      let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
      UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
      application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

I already enabled pushNotifications and background modes in xcode, already check my certificates but the problem stands. Someone could help me? I m spending more than a week on it.. What I did is right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following points, based on documentation for [Pushing Background Updates to Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app) mentions

1.

> To send a background notification, create a remote notification with
> an aps dictionary that includes only the content-available key, as
> shown in Listing 1. You may include custom keys in the payload, but
> the aps dictionary must not contain any keys that would trigger user
> interactions.

2. 

> Additionally, the notification’s POST request should contain the
> apns-push-type header field with a value of background, and the
> apns-priority field with a value of 5.

3. 

> - If something force quits or kills the app, the system discards the
>   held notification. If the user launches the app, the system
>   immediately delivers the held notification.
> - To deliver a background
>   notification, the system wakes your app in the background.

4. (I don't see `didReceiveRemoteNotification` in you `appDelegate`'s code)

> On iOS it then calls your app delegate’s
> `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)`
> method.

Additionally [Sending Notification Requests to APNs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns#2947607) states:

5.

> Use the background push type for notifications that deliver content in
> the background, and don’t trigger any user interactions. If you set
> this push type, the apns-topic header field must use your app’s bundle
> ID as the topic. Always use priority 5. Using priority 10 is an error.

If the above checklist is satisfied, it should work. You can provide final contents of the notification you are sending, or the payload you receive in notification while app is running.